# Magento 1: will the EE code be made available after EOL?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1

As most of you know, Magento 1 EOL is coming (November 2018) and I was wondering what's going to be the status of the EE code.

My question : **is there a chance Magento will release the EE code publicly after M1 end of life** so people can, for example, release LTS patches ?

Comment: Why would they release it? And why would EE merchants stay on it past EOL. I guess for them the merchants on EE are the ones that will need the extra protection or liability that would break after EOL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think this is a question that the community can answer and it's hypothetical. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask